# Solr - unexpected sorting order and sortMissingLast

Tags: sorting, solr

I've got `text` type defined as below:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    ...
```

And a couple of fields using given type. One of these fields is a `title` field, which is always defined and not missing, nor empty for any of the documents. When sorting by this field, either `asc` or `desc` Solr would however **not** return documents in the given order, but, seemingly random. Only after adding `sortMissingLast="true"` to type declaration sorting was in proper order.

Can anybody explain to me why is it so? In my understanding, `sortMissingLast` shouldn't be in effect when using sort, as a) it's connected with insertion of documents b) all documents in my collection have this field defined.

Reading further:

`If sortMissingLast="true", then a sort on this field will cause documents without the field to come after documents with the field, regardless of the requested sort order (asc or desc)`.

I do indeed have other fields that use the same `text` type, however all of them are present. They might be empty, but they're present within the document.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a sample index with your `fieldType`, that is `text`. when i tried with `title asc` my result was below response

```
    "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":1,
        "params":{
          "sort":"title asc",
          "indent":"true",
          "q":"*:*",
          "wt":"json"}},
      "response":{"numFound":10,"start":0,"docs":[
          {
            "id":["123"],
            "title":"awesome designs_takeaway",
            "lastmodified":"f75a2e26-cb41-4028-abb2-bcd7f61e4f9e",
            "_version_":1538551521252212736},
          {
            "id":["124"],
            "title":"breathtaking_designs takeaway",
            "lastmodified":"170b3857-d906-44df-950c-547c25b4e594",
            "_version_":1538551543494606848},
          {
            "id":["125"],
            "title":"curtain raiser",
            "lastmodified":"ea7149d5-449f-4d69-919b-617b90420381",
            "_version_":1538573292313509888},
          {
            "id":["126"],
            "title":"defying gravity_008",
            "lastmodified":"82844b75-24ba-4b2f-be20-9bb3fe83e6b1",
            "_version_":1538551590630195200},
          {
            "id":["127"],
            "title":"emancipation_of the poor",
            "lastmodified":"d19482a5-1666-4d4e-a40e-eb93c00eca7e",
            "_version_":1538551627310432256},
          {
            "id":["128"],
            "title":"functioning of the-metadata",
            "lastmodified":"7b07f281-1268-48cc-aee6-7a6636702ba5",
            "_version_":1538551653171462144},
          {
            "id":["130"],
            "title":"graphics enhancer 101",
            "lastmodified":"67fd79d6-2ae5-4597-b2e1-128bfd815b67",
            "_version_":1538551680471138304},
          {
            "id":["131"],
            "title":"half-hearted attempt",
            "lastmodified":"abb4707c-8392-4595-aaeb-fbf6d4f098b1",
            "_version_":1538551699761790976},
          {
            "id":["132"],
            "title":"INK jet corporation",
            "lastmodified":"b29ba3af-f3da-49d1-bd45-f7d277c53cff",
            "_version_":1538551727666495488},
          {
            "id":["136"],
            "title":"xamarin",
            "filecontent":"bolshevik",
            "lastmodified":"af8a1445-e693-4bac-9ac8-84fa2c9b838d",
            "_version_":1538571040880328704}]
      }}`
```

When i tried with `title desc`.

My response

```
`{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "sort":"title desc",
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"*:*",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":10,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":["136"],
        "title":"xamarin",
        "filecontent":"bolshevik",
        "lastmodified":"af8a1445-e693-4bac-9ac8-84fa2c9b838d",
        "_version_":1538571040880328704},
      {
        "id":["132"],
        "title":"INK jet corporation",
        "lastmodified":"b29ba3af-f3da-49d1-bd45-f7d277c53cff",
        "_version_":1538551727666495488},
      {
        "id":["131"],
        "title":"half-hearted attempt",
        "lastmodified":"abb4707c-8392-4595-aaeb-fbf6d4f098b1",
        "_version_":1538551699761790976},
      {
        "id":["130"],
        "title":"graphics enhancer 101",
        "lastmodified":"67fd79d6-2ae5-4597-b2e1-128bfd815b67",
        "_version_":1538551680471138304},
      {
        "id":["128"],
        "title":"functioning of the-metadata",
        "lastmodified":"7b07f281-1268-48cc-aee6-7a6636702ba5",
        "_version_":1538551653171462144},
      {
        "id":["127"],
        "title":"emancipation_of the poor",
        "lastmodified":"d19482a5-1666-4d4e-a40e-eb93c00eca7e",
        "_version_":1538551627310432256},
      {
        "id":["126"],
        "title":"defying gravity_008",
        "lastmodified":"82844b75-24ba-4b2f-be20-9bb3fe83e6b1",
        "_version_":1538551590630195200},
      {
        "id":["125"],
        "title":"curtain raiser",
        "lastmodified":"ea7149d5-449f-4d69-919b-617b90420381",
        "_version_":1538573292313509888},
      {
        "id":["124"],
        "title":"breathtaking_designs takeaway",
        "lastmodified":"170b3857-d906-44df-950c-547c25b4e594",
        "_version_":1538551543494606848},
      {
        "id":["123"],
        "title":"awesome designs_takeaway",
        "lastmodified":"f75a2e26-cb41-4028-abb2-bcd7f61e4f9e",
        "_version_":1538551521252212736}]
  }}`
```

As you can see, i am getting expected results . I used `Solr v 5.3.2` . Your type `text` also does not tokenize text into parts and therefore is a good candidate for `sorting` . So no use of thinking in that way to solve the problem .The   `sortMissingLast` and `sortMissingFirst` parameters totally serve different purpose , though i did used them to replicate your observations, i saw only expected results . And as you say that your every document has a `title` field,so i also kept `title` field in all my documents, therefore there was  of no use of `sortMissingLast` and `sortMissingFirst` parameters, as they will affect the document set having document having no `title` field in them, your results should not deviate from what i got . This only trickles down to the inference, that may be your solr has a bug . If you are not using the same version as mine , try your documents once on the version `5.3.2` or some version different from yours. Or can you provide a subset of titles from your side that are getting sorted as wrong just as to see how they are getting analyzed , if you don't suspect Solr is having a bug. Let me know if that helps :) .

Comment: It indeed might to do with the Solr version - we're using 4.10.1. Yup - I've had the same thoughts about `sortMissingLast` and `sortMissingFirst`. Will try your test data on my version later on, and will come back with results

Comment: Sure ! let me know the results ! btw , also try testing my data on a solr 5.3.2 version yourself so as to confirm that my observations are not incidental . Installing and testing a new solr version on localhost won't take much of your time . Meanwhile i could not find much evidence as to why such a behavior is demonstrated by your Solr . Will try replicating my data on solr 4.10.1 myself too !!